# Some questions about the closure of the graph of projection $\Bbb P^n\dashrightarrow\Bbb P^{n-1}$ from Mumford's book.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following is from David Mumford's Algebraic geometry I Complex Projective Varieties, page 32.

Let $\mathbb{P}^n_X$ and $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y$ be spaces with coordinates $(X_0,...,X_n),(Y_0,...,Y_{n-1}).$
Consider the so-called projection:

$p:\mathbb{P}^n_X - (0,...,0,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y$, $(x_0,...,x_n) \mapsto (x_0,...,x_{n-1})$

$P_n = (0,...,0,1)$ is called the center of the projection. $p$ is surjective and for $x\in \mathbb{P}^n_X, x \neq P_n, p^{-1}(p(x))$ is ***the line joining $P_n$ and $x$ minus the point $P_n$.*** Now $p$ also extends to a rational correspondence from the whole variety $\mathbb{P}^n_X$ to $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y$: define

$$Z = V(...,Y_iX_j-Y_jX_i,...)_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1} \subset \mathbb{P}^n_X \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y$$

One sees immediately that $Z$ is ***the union of the graph*** of $p$ and the pairs $(P_n,y)$, any $y \in \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y$.In other words the center $P_n$ is "blown up" by $Z$ to the whole $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y$. Moreover $Z$ is irreducible, hence is a variety itself: let $E=\{P_n\} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y \subset Z$. Then by (2.23), $Z-E$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n_X - \{P_n\}$ ***hence is irreducible.*** But for all $y \in \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_Y, $let $l_y$ be the line $p^{-1}(y)$ plus $P_n$. Then ($l_y - \{P_n\}) \times \{y\} \subset Z-E.$ ***Therefore $l_y \times \{y\} \subset$ (Zariski closure of $Z-E$).*** In particular, ($P_n,y)\in \overline{Z-E}$, hence $E \subset \overline{Z-E}$, i.e., ***$Z$ is irreducible***.

My questions:

1. What is "the line joining $P_n$ and $x$ minus the point $P_n$? I'm sure that $p^{-1}(p(x_0:...:x_n)) = p^{-1}(x_0:...:x_{n-1}) = \{(x_0:...:x_{n-1}:s) \in \mathbb{P}^n_X |s \in \mathbb{C}, (x_0,...,x_{n-1})\neq(0,...,0)\}$
   I get the feeling that this is indeed a straight line containing $P_n$ at $s = ∞$, but can you explain it more rigorously?
2. Why $Z-E$ is irreducible? i.e., why $\mathbb{P}^n_X -\{P_n\}$ is irreducible?
3. Why ($l_y - \{P_n\}) \times \{y\} \subset Z-E.$ means $l_y \times \{y\} \subset$ (Zariski closure of $Z-E$)?. I am probably not familiar with taking Zariski closure.
4. Why $E \subset \overline{Z-E}$, means $Z$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $P_n$ is not in your line because $p$ cannot be extended to $P_n=(0:...:0:1)$ as you cannot have all your coordinates being $0$ for hommogeneous coordinates of a projective space.
2. $\mathbb{P}^n-\{P_n\}$ is irreducible because it is an open subset of an irreducible set. $\mathbb{P}^n$ is irreducible and a point is closed. Indeed, if $\mathbb{P}^n-\{P_n\}=W_1\cup W_2$ for some closed set $W_i$ then, $\mathbb{P}^n=W_1\cup W_2\cup\{P_n\}$ so that contradicts $\mathbb{P}^n$ being irreducible.
3. The Zariski closure of $l_y-\{P_n\}$ is just $l_y$. So Zariksi closure of $(l_y-\{P_n\})\times \{y\}$ is $l_y\times\{y\}$. Now, $A\subset B \implies \bar{A}\subset \bar{B}$ so this follows.

Comment: Could you explain why the Zariski closure of $l_y - \{P_n\}$ is just $l_y$?